# .htaccess redirection not working perhaps missing regular expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am using the following regular expression in .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^js_embed/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/[0-9]+ /users/$1/js_embed_$2.html [R=301,L]
```

basically what I am trying is to do is, redirect

/js_embed/platform/37482 to /users/$1/js_embed_$2.html

however I am getting blank $2 value, I mean I am expecting $2=37482

I am missing something in my regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing braces around `[0-9]+` ?

```
RewriteRule ^js_embed/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/([0-9]+) /users/$1/js_embed_$2.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: with parenthesis around second capture I am getting redirected to

users/$1/js_embed_.html

still getting $2 as blank

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parentheses around the second capture expression

```
RewriteRule ^js_embed/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/([0-9]+) /users/$1/js_embed_$2.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: with parenthesis around second capture I am getting redirected to

users/$1/js_embed_.html

still getting $2 as blank

Comment: @Rahul your initial 301 is probably cached in your browser. Try running the same thing in private browsing mode

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a second capture group. Perhaps you mean...

```
RewriteRule ^js_embed/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/([0-9]+) /users/$1/js_embed_$2.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: what I am trying is to redirect /js_embed/platform/37482 to /users/platform/js_embed_37482.html so I guess 37482 should be captured as second group